# Why does נהמא דכיסופא make sense at all between lovers?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, reward-punishment

[This preliminary question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60193/how-the-idea-of-the-bread-of-shame-aligns-with-free-will) asks about what N"D is.

The [נהמא דכיסופא](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%90_%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%90) is a possible explanation for why should we suffer in this world to receive the reward in the afterworld. I tried to verify that:

- My father-in-law bought me (us) a new car, he said he loves me. I was very happy and thanked him and felt no shame.
- My wife bought me a new GoPro, she said she loves me. I was very happy and thanked her and felt no shame.

If this principle seemingly does not work on Earth, why should we feel any shame to receive free gifts from our Father in Heaven/ב"ז (what is [נהמא דכיסופא](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%90_%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%90) about)?

Comment: It seems that the shame should come when such gifts are undeserved. In general, no work = undeserved, but not in the cases you describe, since presumably, you have done things to find favor in the eyes of your wife and in-laws.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות What work did I do with my relatives? I stresses that they didn't say "you helped my so here's your reward" the simply love me. Don't you buy stuff to your wife and kids JUST because you love them?

Comment: @AlBerko I agree with what you wrote. G-d loves us. The Torah calls us His children. G-d would be displeased if we study in solitude, disconnect ourselves from society, and refrain from the goods of the world which G-d have made for us. One could be humble and show gratitude, thankfulness, but should never be shameful. Unless they didn't deserve it, but then, they should be more than grateful and return to performing more mitzvot.

Comment: @AlBerko and why do you love them? Why do they love you? Because of the relationship you have built with them...

Comment: @AlBerko You are focusing on the wrong perspective (The perspective of the human observer, the one created). The concept behind 'Bread of Shame' is not to avoid shame. It is to maximize ones ability to appreciate the good (The perspective of the Holy One, blessed be He, the Creator). See the beginning of Derech HaShem by Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato for details.

Comment: @DonielF the other question asks how it works, I ask "that does not make sense, because it shouldn't work between lovers.

Comment: @AlBerko Shouldn’t a complete answer to “explain נהמא דכיסופא” also answer “why does it make sense”?

Comment: @DonielF I would agree that it makes sense for בחינת עבדים - for G-ds servants, but we have a higher form of relations with Hashem. what I'm asking about.

Comment: @AlBerko Again, shouldn’t a complete answer to that question address this one too?

Comment: Magid meisharim bereshis 14 tevet

Comment: @DonielF Did you understand my differentiation or not? it seems that you didn't, just like Shmuel's answer. When at work, it's perfectly logical that you don't expect to get rewarded without work, but for lovers this principle doesn't work AT ALL. So for those who hold that we relate to G-d as Sons or spouse/lovers Nehama is irrelevant. IMHO.

Comment: Is there any reason to think that the way your emotions work on Earth correlates to how your “emotions” will work in Heaven?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100561/discussion-between-alex-and-al-berko).

Answer (score 1):

Your premise `The נהמא דכיסופא is a possible explanation for why should we suffer in this world to receive the reward in the afterworld` is potentially without merit.

The Magid Meisharim writes ([Bereishis, 14 Tevet](https://www.sefaria.org/Maggid_Meisharim.2.8?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) that this is a spiritual shame:

> אבל רזא דמילתא במה דאת מתרץ דנשמתין עד לא אתו לעלמא דמו למאן דאכיל נהמא דמלכא בלא פולחנא ומשום דא אמרו נוח לו לאדם שנברא כלומר דגשמתן מיכספן מגרמייהו למיכל נהמא דמלכא בלא פולחנא ומשום הכי מתאוות למיתי לעלמא ונוח להם להבראות כדי למיפק מההוא כיסופא בעי למיתי להאי עלמא למתעסק בתורה ובמצות לעבדה ולשמרה ויכלון נהמא בלא כיסופא
>   Until souls reach this world, it can be compared to one who eats the King's bread without serving Him. That is why they stated that it is better that one be created. Meaning, the souls feel shame from themselves by eating the King's bread without serving Him. This is why there is a desire to bring them into this world and is it better to be created. In order to deflect that shame, one must come into this world to be busy with the Torah and Mitzvos to do it and guard it; they will then be eating bread without shame.

Comment: This is exactly what I object: "מיכספן מגרמייהו למיכל נהמא דמלכא בלא פולחנא" - it only applies to servants, not sons or lovers. This is the whole difference. M"M only addresses the part when we refer to ourselves as servants - עבדים and forget when we call ourselves בנים. So your answer does not address the status of lovers.

Comment: Good point however, the two are not comparable and this is an answer I’d stand in front of

Comment: If your father in asked you to do a favor for him with that car would you feel no shame in refusing?